# Nesting two stream builders causing bad state error

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am fetching data from two different firestore collections and this is my code

```
 StreamBuilder(
           stream: Firestore.instance.collection('items').snapshots(),
           builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot){

             if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
               return CupertinoActivityIndicator();
             }
             if(snapshot.data != null){
               return ListView.builder(
                 itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                 itemBuilder: (context,index){
                   return Column(
                     children: <Widget>[

                       Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['name']),
                       Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['color']),
                       Text(snapshot.data.documents[index]['lifetime']),

                       Container(
                         child: StreamBuilder(
                           stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users')
                            .document(userid).collection('Quantity')
                            .document(snapshot.data.documents[index]['id']).snapshots(),
                           builder: (BuildContext context, snap){

                             if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                              return CupertinoActivityIndicator();
                            }
                            if(snap.data != null){
                              return Container(
                              child:  Text(snap.data.documents.length)
                              );
                            }
                           },
                         ),
                       )

                     ],
                   );
                 });
             }
           },
         )
```

It is giving me error but when I use futurebuilder inside streambuilder everything works fine and I also used stream broadcast but it is also giving me same error.
Here is the code which I used for broadcast stream

```
  StreamController _controller = StreamController.broadcast();
        Stream getItems() async*{
          Firestore.instance.collection('items').snapshots().listen((data){
            _controller.add(data);
          })
          yield* _controller.stream;
        }
```

[image: This is the error I am getting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't create a new `Stream` inside the `StreamBuilder`. When you do:

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('items').snapshots(),
```

And

```dart
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users')
    .document(userid).collection('Quantity')
    .document(snapshot.data.documents[index]['id']).snapshots(),
```

Each time your `build()` function is called a new `StreamBuilder` is created, so `Firestore.instance.collection()...snapshots()` is called, returning a new `Stream` each time.

You should convert your widget to a `StatefulWidget` and initialize your `Stream` on `initState()`, passing it as a class variable to your `StreamBuilder`. The nested `StreamBuilder` can also be transformed into a `StatefulWidget` and created in place, but initialized on the same manner. Just pay attention that you might need a `Key` for showing it correctly on a `ListView`.

Also if you want to convert a Single Subscription `Stream` to a Broadcast `Stream` you just have to call `asBroadcastStream` to convert it.

Comment: Thank you so much everything is working fine now but with this method my code looks more complicated than the nested stream builders. I still do not understand why providing streams direct to stream builders gives error?

Comment: I think it's related to the 2 StreamBuilders sharing the same context, so when the outter one emits, the inner one is recreated with the same context so maybe it's getting a reference to the old stream to subscribe. This might be repeated to the StreamBuilder logic on dealing with old and new streams being passed, would have to investigate deeper.